# PreliminaryEstimateValue using Lookback API

Tags: rally, lookbackapi, wsapi

I'm trying to get the PreliminaryEstimateValue for PortfolioItem/Feature using Lookback API, but it always comes empty. And PreliminaryEstimate can't be Hydrated as per error message in response either.

**Shouldn't PreliminaryEstimateValue be returning correctly using Lookback API?**

WSAPI calls work fine though.

Request:

```
{
"find": {
    "_ProjectHierarchy": 90681998188,
    "_TypeHierarchy": "PortfolioItem/Feature",
    "Release": {"$in": [131091429492]},


    "__At": "2018-03-23T00Z"
},
"fields": [ "Name", "FormattedID", "PreliminaryEstimateValue", "PreliminaryEstimate", "State"],
"hydrate" : ["State", "PreliminaryEstimate"]
```

}

response:

```
{
    "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
    "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
    "Errors": [],
    "Warnings": [
        "PreliminaryEstimate is not a field that can be hydrated."
    ],
    "GeneratedQuery": {
        "find": {
            "_ProjectHierarchy": 90681998188,
            "_TypeHierarchy": {
                "$in": [
                    46772407280
                ]
            },
            "Release": {
                "$in": [
                    131091429492
                ]
            },
            "$and": [
                {
                    "_ValidFrom": {
                        "$lte": "2018-03-23T00:00:00.000Z"
                    },
                    "_ValidTo": {
                        "$gt": "2018-03-23T00:00:00.000Z"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "_ValidFrom": {
                "$lte": "2018-06-19T20:31:00.287Z"
            }
        },
        "limit": 100,
        "skip": 0,
        "fields": {
            "Name": 1,
            "PreliminaryEstimateValue": 1,
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 1,
            "State": 1,
            "Project": 1,
            "_UnformattedID": 1,
            "_TypeHierarchy": "['$slice': -1]"
        }
    },
    "TotalResultCount": 9,
    "HasMore": false,
    "StartIndex": 0,
    "PageSize": 100,
    "ETLDate": "2018-06-19T20:31:00.287Z",
    "Results": [
        {
            "State": "In-Progress",
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 46772407339,
            "Name": "XXX",
            "FormattedID": "F68452"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XXX",
            "State": "Exploring",
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 46772407352,
            "FormattedID": "F64513"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XXX",
            "State": "Exploring",
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 46772407364,
            "FormattedID": "F64765"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XXX",
            "State": "In-Progress",
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 46772407352,
            "FormattedID": "F54674"
        },
        {
            "State": "Exploring",
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 46772407352,
            "Name": "XXX",
            "FormattedID": "F67562"
        },
        {
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 46772407339,
            "Name": "XXX",
            "State": "In-Progress",
            "FormattedID": "F40534"
        },
        {
            "State": "In-Progress",
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 80332343408,
            "Name": "XXX",
            "FormattedID": "F69302"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XXX",
            "FormattedID": "F66688"
        },
        {
            "Name": "XXX",
            "State": "In-Progress",
            "PreliminaryEstimate": 46772407373,
            "FormattedID": "F47343"
        }
    ],
    "ThreadStats": {
        "cpuTime": "16.131516",
        "waitTime": "0",
        "waitCount": "0",
        "blockedTime": "0",
        "blockedCount": "0"
    },
    "Timings": {
        "preProcess": 0,
        "findEtlDate": 86,
        "allowedValuesDisambiguation": 1201,
        "mongoQuery": 23,
        "authorization": 3,
        "formattedId": 0,
        "suppressNonRequested": 0,
        "compressSnapshots": 0,
        "allowedValuesHydration": 307,
        "TOTAL": 1620
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like PreliminaryEstimateValue is available in Lookback Api.
You'll have to just query wsapi for the PreliminaryEstimate objects in your workspace for that portfolio item type first and then cross reference them in the data after the fact.

Comment: Thanks. I did that.